POST request forbidden on cosmosdb endpoint
Im following a tutorial on cosmosdb with CORE SQL and trying to create a database.
EndpointUri and Key are correct, copied from cosmosdb account => settings => keys
const string EndpointUri = "https://fergerg.azure.com:443/";
const string Key = "gvfvfdevgrvgre";

Then when creating a database:
        string databaseName = "demoDB_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);

        client = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, Key);
        database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);

Error 403 is returned

Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors
occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden
(403); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: e10466; Reason:
({"code":"Forbidden","message":""Operation 'POST' on resource 'dbs'
is not allowed through Azure Cosmos DB endpoint. Please switch on such
operations for your account, or perform this operation through Azure
Resource Manager, Azure Portal, Azure CLI or Azure
Powershell"\r\nActivityId: 14d3a978f6ee10466,
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0"} RequestUri:
https://sql-iknn-.documents.azure.com/dbs

So POST is forbidden on endpoint dbs:
documents.azure.com/dbs
I think this has changed, that this worked before but is now not possible anymore out of the box.
How do I give permission to send POST requests to this endpoint from remote code?

Refer this document for forbidden exceptions.


Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: e10466;

The above error is occurred due to mismatch of authentication credentials, insufficient permissions, or incorrect configuration of the firewall or virtual network settings. Make sure to allow public access to the db if there is no need of private connectivity. Refer this document for more information on forbidden exceptions.
Below is an example to create a database in Azure Cosmos DB:
class Program
{
    private static readonly string EndpointUri = "*****";
    private static readonly string Key = "*****";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string databaseName = "secondDb" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);

        using (CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, Key))
        {
            DatabaseResponse response = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Database '{databaseName}' created successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create database '{databaseName}'. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
Database secondDb4a663 created successfully.



you've created the cosmosdb account with SQL CORE API?
